# Compiler error when comparing pointer and integer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to make sure the user enters a value between 1 and 20, but this compile error came up when I tried to compile my code:

> error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE=20;

void bubbleSort(int numbers[], int SIZE);


int main()
{
    int numbers[SIZE]= {26, 45, 56, 12, 78, 74, 39, 22, 5, 90, 87, 32, 28, 11, 93, 62, 79, 53, 22, 51};
    int value=0;
    bool found;

    cout << "Today we are going to be searching for values." << endl;
    cout << "These are the values you have to choose from" << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        cout << numbers[i]<<"; ";


    cout << "What value would you like to search for?" << endl;

    cin >> value;

    do
    {
        cout << "Make sure to enter a value that's in the list." << endl;
        cin >> value;
        found=false;
        for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        {
            if (value==numbers[i])
            {
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            cout << "Enter a valid value !" << endl;
    }
    while (!found);

    bubbleSort(numbers, SIZE);



    return 0;
}

void bubbleSort (int numbers[], int SIZE)
{
    int maxElement=0;
    int index=0;


    cout << "Original order:" << endl;
    cout << numbers << endl;


    for(maxElement=SIZE-1; maxElement>=0; maxElement--)
    {
        for(index=0; index<=maxElement-1; index++)
        {
            if(numbers[index]>numbers[index+1])
            {
                swap(numbers[index], numbers[index+1]);
            }
        }
    }

}

void swap(int &a, int &b)
{
    int temp;
    temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;

    cout << "Bubble Sorted:" << a << b << endl;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: `while(value!=numbers)` is meaningless nonsense. What are you trying to do with it? Also, `cout << numbers` doesn't do what you seem to think it does (it does not print the contents of `numbers` array).

Comment: Can you explain how did you come to the conclusion, that comparison `value!=numbers` will check if `value` is between 1 and 20?

Comment: I thought since SIZE was assigned to the array that perhaps by values=numbers(the array) it would check all of the numbers in the array. 

@AlgirdasPreidžius

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that the input is between 1 and 20 then it's easier to write:

```
while(value<1 || value>20)
{
    cout << "The value chosen must be between 1 and 20." << endl;
    cin>> value;
}
```

If you want to check it the value is in the list of 20 integer values that you put in the array, you can't just compare a single integer with an array.  You have to search in the array, for example with [`find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/):

```
while(find(numbers, numbers+SIZE, value)==numbers+SIZE)
{
    cout << "The value chosen must be between in the list of authorized values" << endl;
    cin>> value;
}
```

By the way, your `cout<<numbers` will not work as you expect ! Either make a for loop to iterate through the numbers and display them all,  or try:

```
copy (numbers, numbers+SIZE, ostream_interator<int>(cout,"; "));
```

**Edit: Alternatives without algorithms**

If you're not allowed to use `copy()` or `find()` ,  you have to work with for loops:

```
// for displaying 
for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    cout << numbers[i]<<"; "; 
cout <<endl;
```

And for the finding, either you create a function for it, or you have to rework your loop structure:

```
...
bool found; 
do {
      cin >> value;
      found=false; 
      for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
           if (value==numbers[i]) {
               found=true; 
               break; 
           }
       }
      if (!found) 
          cout << "Enter a valid value !" << endl;
} while (!found); 
...
```

Comment: Do you have advice to check if the value is in the 20 list of integers without find? We don't use that in my class yet haha. It would be confusing to explain.

Comment: @Christphe forgot to tag you

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm getting quite a weird output, however, and I'm not sure why. Everything you did made sense. http://prntscr.com/bx1y6h

This is the output I'm getting. It's all cocky. 
@Christophe

I edited my original post to show you what I now have. It's not displaying correctly and when I entered a correct value it said it was wrong.

Comment: @fbhsie remove the cin input before the do. And the first statement after the do. The do loop always execute the loop body once. So in your case the  input before the do would always be ignored and the value overwritten with the input made in the loop